# cql poor write perfromance and write timeouts with default configuration

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a csv file with about 30 columns and 1 millions rows (less than 1GB in size).

I am using a single machine/node on localhost and my keyspace has:

`WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};`

The columns are mostly doubles, with a few strings.

I have tried two methods to load this into cassandra using the default cassandra.yaml:

1) using the `COPY` function directly from CQL

2) using the cqlengine python driver wrapped around CQL with multiple scripts and batched inserts on a set of broken up csv files

Both approaches seem to take over an hour with default cassandra settings on both linux/windows. Is this really the speed I should expect? I was expecting something on the order of minutes.

If not, what are the key options I should focus on, or how can I quickly diagnose what is the bottleneck? This seems like a trivial use case (admittedly not a focus of Cassandra), so I'm having trouble understanding why it should be so challenging.

I've tried disabling commit logs, and changing other options. I'm trying to understand the source of this performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

You might find http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/performance.html useful. Switching `COPY FROM` from a synchronous execution to a callback chaining gave us 10x increase in performance [image]

Comment: Wow, that's quite the improvement!

Comment: I will try this now, this looks like what I was hoping for.